# Fast search with enumerate in text document

Tags: python-3.x

I need fast search for line in text document with compare from other output and if I have equal line in text document, I have to do some calculation with index so I have to use enumerate, then want get other line from my document list through current index, so last one is a point, which I want get much faster than I have it now. database is a long list of one lines, one under another. so I have try many variants, if some of it works faster, it can't work with enumerate.

Can you help me make this search faster?

So here how I want it, but this way works very slow with data over 1500 lines, not to big, but fact, works slow, if text exist in line of text document, I need  fast find of (y) through the text index and calculation:

```
with open('C:\path\doc.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if (text) in line: 
            if i % onx:
                 y = lines[i + 4]
                 print (y)
```

if I go this way, work faster, but how to use enumerate here:

```
d = {}

f = open("C:\path\doc.txt","r")
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    l = len(line)+1
    for i in range(1,l):
        d[line[:i]] = True
f.close()


while True:
    w = ('text')
    if not w:
        break

    if w in d:
        print (w)
```

same here I can't use enumerate directly and can only  get (line) as second variable, but it certainly makes it worse:

```
with open('C:\path\doc.txt', 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:
        if (text) in line:
          print (line)
```

Comment: Remember to [escape backslashes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) in your strings! Or make them raw strings with `r''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in this way will lead to O(n*m) search complexity, where n and m are the sizes for the output and text file. Using enums, is likely going to be very [slow](https://bugs.python.org/issue23486)... If you generate a dictionary that maps strings (file lines) to their indexes you can reduce the complexity of your search to O(n+m).